# grep and like when subsetting with parentheses

Tags: r

I am working with the following code:

```
server = function(input, output) {

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data <- test_results
    if (input$rn != "All") {
      #data <- data[data$rn == input$rn,]
      #data = data[grep(input$rn, data$rn),]
      data = data[data$rn %like% input$rn,]
    }
    data
  }))

}
```

The problem is the string matching using both grep and %like% works when I have input values like a == 6. The problem is both lines are not working for other input values in my data that have parentheses like abs(a) == 6. How do I fix this line so that string matching works with and without parentheses? Thanks!

UPDATE FOR REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

```
a = matrix(list("abs(a) = 2", "a = 2" , 1, 1), 2, 2)
```

As an example, I need a generic way to filter this matrix where both abs(a) = 2 and a = 2 work.

a = a[a[0] %like% "filter field"] does not work like in the example

%in% works but only matches when the strings are exactly the same
I want the functionality of %like% but like is not working if the string has parentheses.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: Updated but hard to make a good example because of the problem. I just need a string contains function that doesn't break when parentheses are in the string. %like& and grep are not working for abs(a) but work for just a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
data = data[gsub("[()]", "", data$rn) %like% gsub("[()]", "", input$rn),]
```